# Unable to load nevron winform ui controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, nevron

I need to use Surface charts in my winforms application for that I have downloaded  `nevron.nov.charts` through Nuget packages in Visual Studio, when I am trying to add `NchartViewControl` to my design page I am getting `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`. Please find the attached images and guide me in solving the issue.

['System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF1j6.png),
['system.TypeLoadException:GenericArguments'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wpeq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the NOV Chart provides support only for 2D charting at the moment and you will not be able to plot Surface charts. We are planning to implement 3D charting functionality in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio shows these exceptions when the version of the controls installed in the toolbox differs from the version of the controls referenced by your project. Most probably you have an old version of Nevron Open Vision installed on your PC and it has registered some controls to the toolbox of Visual Studio and then you have installed a NuGet package that contains more recent versions of these controls. They differ from the ones registered in the toolbox and that is why Visual Studio throws an exception.

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

### Solution 1: Update your NOV installation to the latest version

1. Uninstall the version of NOV you have on your computer
2. Download and install the [latest version of Nevron Open Vision](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx).

All NOV assemblies will then be installed to the GAC and you won't have to download any NuGet packages to use NOV controls. You will also receive a set of new Visual Studio project templates for creating NOV applications, for example "NOV Windows Forms Chart Application", "NOV Windows Forms Diagram Application", etc. [Click here to see a screenshot](https://www.nevron.com/NIMG.axd?i=Misc/OpenVision2016.2/General-improvements.png) of the project templates that come with NOV.

### Solution 2: Update your NOV toolbox items

1. Uninstall the Nevron NuGet packages of your project
2. Right click the references of your project and select "Manage NuGet Packages"
3. Search for the "Nevron Open Vision" package and install it. It contains the latest version of all NOV assemblies
4. Right click the header of the tab in the toolbox containing the NOV controls in the toolbox and select "Delete Tab" to delete it
5. Right click an empty area in the toolbox and select "Add Tab"
6. Name the tab "NOV Controls", right click in it and select "Choose Items..."
7. In the dialog that opens click "Browse..." and select the "Nevron.Nov.WinFormControls.dll" assembly of the Nevron Open Vision nuget package. It is located in the "packages\NevronOpenVision.{version}\lib\net40" subfolder of your project.